Is There Syntax Highlighting Support in the LyX Editor?
I'm working with LyX 2.4.1 on Windows 11 using the XeLaTeX engine. I've been trying to set up syntax highlighting for Python code through a custom local layout file, but I'm stuck—I can only get a black background with white font in the editor.
The PDF output looks great(!), so no issues there, but I’m hoping to achieve some basic syntax highlighting directly in the LyX editor itself. I know LyX is generally focused on layout and typesetting, but has anyone managed to set up or find a workaround for syntax highlighting in the editor?
Any tips or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
